# Closest vs Parents

Tags: jquery

Estava lendo a documentação do jQuery e acabei percebendo a semelhança entre os métodos **`closest`** e **`parents`**.

Ele cita as diferenças entre os métodos, afirmando que "são sutis, porém significantes".

Lendo as diferenças percebi esse detalhe no método `closest` ele vai procurando até encontrar o elemento que corresponda ao seletor enviado. Já no método `parents`, ele pega todos os elementos e adiciona em uma lista e depois faz a comparação.

Aparentemente o `closest` é melhor, olhando performance. Isso é verdade? Existe algum caso que seja melhor usar o `parents`?

Comment: "Melhor" é uma palavra muito maleável.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tudo vai depender do uso.

A própria documentação do JQuery explica as diferenças através de uma [tabela comparativa](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

- O método `closest` começa a busca no próprio elemento, enquanto o método `parents` começa no elemento pai
- O método `closest` busca até encontrar um elemento que satisfaça o seletor ( podendo ser ele mesmo ), enquanto o método `parents` vai adicionar todos os pais do elemento numa lista e depois filtra a lista para retornar os elementos que satisfaçam o seletor
- O método `closest` retornará um ou nenhum elemento, enquanto o método `parents` retornará nenhum ou uma lista de elementos, na ordem inversa ao explicitado no documento

Dessa forma, a escolha do método não está nem tão relacionada a performance em si, mas sim ao caso que se deseja usar.