# Como funciona o .closest() no JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Olá, gostaria de saber se estou interpretando errado o comando, ou se estou fazendo algo errado na implementação.

Traduzindo livremente, `closest` significa "mais próximo". Mas ao clicar em um elemento e pedir o `closest()` dele, ele me traz o próprio elemento.

No snippet a seguir, a minha intenção era que ele desse `alert` no contador da linha anterior, porém, se você clicar na linha 3, ele retorna `undefined`

```js
$('tr').click(function () {
 
  var linha = $(this)
  var cont = linha.attr('contador')
  var ant = (cont - 1);
  
  alert(
  linha.closest('tr[contador="' + ant + '"]').attr('contador')
  )
 
});
```

```css
tr{
  line-height: 40px
}

.vermelho{ background-color: red; }
.verde{ background-color: green; }
.azul{ background-color: blue; }
.amarelo{ background-color: yellow; }
.roxo{ background-color: purple; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="500px">
<tr id="tr-1" contador="1" class="vermelho"><td>teste 1</td></tr>
<tr id="tr-2" contador="2" class="azul"><td>teste 2</td></tr>
<tr id="tr-3" contador="3" class="verde"><td>teste 3</td></tr>
<tr id="tr-4" contador="4" class="amarelo"><td>teste 4</td></tr>
<tr id="tr-5" contador="5" class="roxo"><td>teste 5</td></tr>
</table>
```

A [documentação no site](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) do `JQuery` diz o seguinte:

> Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied
>   selector

Então (corrija-me se estiver errado), ele deveria achar a linha de cima, não? Já que ele percorre a DOM acima dele. Ou estou interpretando errado? Como deveria funcionar o `.closest()` então?

Comment: os `tr` que voce tem são todos `siblings`, por isso retorna `undefined`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O método `.closest()` encontra o elemento **pai** mais próximo que satisfaça a condição do seletor, [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15400/closest-vs-parents) tem uma breve explicação do `closest()` e o compara também com o `parent()`, nota que o `closest()` começa a busca no próprio elemento.

No teu caso, todos os `tr` estão no mesmo nível de hierarquia, diferentemente da `table` que seria o elemento **pai** de todos os demais `tr`, logo se tu mudar o teu código p/ `linha.closest('table')`, ele vai encontrar a `table`.

Segue um snippet com um exemplo adaptado do site [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_closest.asp) que mostra claramente essa relação hierárquica.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("span").closest("li").css({
    "color": "red",
    "border": "2px solid red"
  });

  $("span").closest("ul").css({
    "color": "green",
    "border": "2px solid green"
  });
});
```

```css
.ancestors *{
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  color: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="ancestors">body (great-great-grandparent)
  <div style="width:500px;">div (great-grandparent)
    <ul>ul (second ancestor - second grandparent)
      <ul>ul (first ancestor - first grandparent)
        <li>li (direct parent - elemento PAI)
          <span>span</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

Repara que o elemento onde amarraste o auscultador de evento é `$('tr').click`, ou seja um `tr`.

O closest faz uma busca mas começando por sí próprio.

Na [documentação diz](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

> matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree

Traduzindo livremente:

> testa o seletor testando **o próprio elemento** e atravessando o DOM através dos seus ancestrais/pais